# How to create a div element only after the last sibling in apply template in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a div element only after the last sibling node. Here is my xml code

```
<Mammal>
<Lion>34</Lion>
<Lion>56</Lion>
<Lion>67</Lion>
</Mammal>
```

The xsl code for this,

```
<xsl:template match="kingdom">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Mammal/Lion"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:kingdom>

<xsl:template match="Mammal/Lion">
<!-- I need an xsl test here to check if a sibling is the last -->
<div>All mamals are printed</div>
<!-- End of test-->
</xsl:template>
```

Please help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="kingdom">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Mammal/Lion"/>
    <div>All mamals are printed</div>
</xsl:kingdom>
```

Comment: sorry no, I need to check another condition as well. So please tell me if there is any other way to do it. Is it possible to check if a sibling is last one inside the template 'Mammal/Lion'?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying. Please edit your question and show a [mcve] including the test for "another condition" and the expected result.

Comment: P.S You can always test if the current node is the last in the [current node list](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-current-node-list) by looking at `position()=last()`. But it shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: Thank you I'll try using this position()=last()

Comment: Sure, why make it simple when it can be complicated...